# NullPointerException in RecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

**Update:** The problem was due to initializing my RecyclerView twice, once globally and another time locally. This caused a NullPointerException due to the fact that the unassigned RecyclerView was being used for my data adapter.

I get a NullPointerException whenever I launch my app. Please don't mark this is a duplicate as I don't think it's exactly a NullPointerException problem as opposed to an issue with how my methods are structured.

My **onCreate()** has a method called `initialise()`, which separates the initialization of the adapter from launch and refresh:

```
private boolean initialise() {
        boolean isOnline = NetworkHelper.isOnline(this);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        retrieveYeets();

        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(() -> {
            if (!isOnline) {
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            } else {

                retrieveYeets();

            }
        });
        return isOnline;
    }
```

The following method completes the adapter creation:

```
private void retrieveYeets() {
        String groupId = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getString("groupId");
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<>(ParseConstants.CLASS_MESSAGE);
        query.whereContains(ParseConstants.KEY_GROUP_ID, groupId);
        query.orderByDescending("lastReplyUpdatedAt");
        query.setLimit(1000);
        query.findInBackground((yeets, e) -> {

            if (mSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }

            if (e == null) {

                // We found messages!
                mYeets = yeets;
                System.out.println(yeets);
                FeedAdapter adapter = new FeedAdapter(getApplicationContext(), yeets);
                adapter.setHasStableIds(true);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        });
    }
```

As you can see, I can print out my list and it is **not null**. I then feed my list into my adapter. Shouldn't this just work? Why the exception?

**Exception:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
      at com.yitter.feed.FeedAdapter.getItemCount(FeedAdapter.java:466)
      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep1(RecyclerView.java:3170)
```

**Adapter:**

The class is quite large but the relevant parts are easy to digest, i.e. you can search **onCreateViewHolder**, **onBindViewHolder**, so I've provided a Gist:

Gist: https://gist.github.com/santafebound/70a82fb9a3349930a030ef66b426a04b

Comment: post your adapter code

Comment: @indramurari I pasted it above.

Comment: can you share your mainActivity code

Comment: @indramurari Here it is: https://gist.github.com/santafebound/d8e2d213eb1dff8050e2524d6f7147bc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got your problem. You have declared `RecyclerView` twice. So in initialise method you have initialised another `RecyclerView` which is null in `retrieveYeets()` method. So just change following line in `initialise()` method

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
```

to

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you. I didn't even realize this would cause a problem. Good lesson learned. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

inside the `getItemCount()` (in the adapter) you return `mYeets.size()`, which fails if mYeets has not been initialized yet (before the data is loaded)

Change `getItemCount()` to:

```
if (mYeets == null) {
 return 0;
} else {
 return mYeets.size();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get the exact same exception, complaining about this line: ``recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);``

Comment: Yes, this is another error ... I can't see your full code, but I'm pretty sure you've declared recyclerView twice (once globaly and once localy). Remove the first word "RecyclerView" from "RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);" in the initialze method.

Comment: This is exactly what the problem was. Thank you. It worked!